# What kind of encoding is this and how do I produce it programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows, registry, vsto

I was creating an Office add-in using Visual Studio tools for Office, and part of deploying/installing the add-in is creating Windows registry entries for it. Visual Studio automatically creates these registry entries for the developer when he or she builds the add-in, but they need to be created by some other means (such as by an installer) when the add-in is being installed/deployed on an end-user's machine. Here is an example of the registry entry I'm questioning:

```
Manifest    REG_SZ    file:///C:/Users/Ryan/Office Projects/C%23/MyProject/addin.vsto
```

How do I programmatically recreate that kind of encoding? I guess it's not URL encoding, because the colon (`:`) is not changed into `%3A`, the spaces are not changed into `%20`s, however the # in "C#" is turned in to a `%23`... so what do I call this type of encoding, and how would I translate an absolute file system path into this type of encoding for the purposes of creating my own installer that would write this sort of registry entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `Uri` is what you want. This example:

```
Debug.WriteLine(new Uri(@"C:\Test\c#file.txt").ToString());
// outputs: file:///C:/Test/c%23file.txt
```

Comment: It's still mysterious to me why Visual Studio created the registry entry with spaces in the path name, whereas the Uri class converts the spaces to %20, but I'm pretty sure the Uri class will do just fine nevertheless. I have a hunch that it will work with either space characters *or* %20s... I shall test it with the Office application.